# JPanel not repainting, even when calling repaint() and revalidate()

Tags: java, colors, jpanel, paintcomponent

Hey guys. I have got a JPanel which changes color when it is clicked (this is handled correctly in another class).

Unfortunately, when I call the repaint() method, it doesn't paint (or it calls the paintComponent method with the old Color value for var currentBGColor -> see code below)

```
public class MyClass extends JPanel {

curentBGColor = Color.red; 
final int SIZE = 70;
public MyClass (){
setPreferredSize (new Dimension (SIZE,SIZE));
}

public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
{
g.setColor (currentBGColor); //I want this to paint white when newColor() is called
g.fillRect (0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());

g.setColor (Color.black);
g.drawLine (0,0,SIZE-1,0);
g.drawLine (0,0,0,SIZE-1);
g.drawLine (0,SIZE-1,SIZE-1,SIZE-1);
g.drawLine (SIZE-1,0,SIZE-1,SIZE-1);
}

void newColor (){
currentBGColor = Color.white;
repaint ();
revalidate();
}
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why it is not painting with the new color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `newColor` from a non-EDT thread, the Swing thread might never know the new value of `currenBGColor`.  You could try making `currentBGColor` `volatile`.

**Edit:**

trying `volatile` was meant as a debugging tool to see if it is a threading issue.  If it is a threading issue, in order to follow the correct Swing threading model, you should not use `volatile` but instead make sure that `newColor` is always called from the Swing event dispatch thread.

Comment: Bingo! Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: @Jimmy: No, volatile is very wrong here and will only serve to confuse. Just don't do it. Yes you should call most all swing calls on the EDT, but I don't know if threading is the issue yet. We need to see how you're calling this method to help you correct it because the code above doesn't show the error, but please don't follow toto's advice here. I know he means well, but it's just plain wrong.

Comment: Yes, I was about to add a comment that it's not the Swing way to do it.  At least it identifies the problem.

Comment: @toto: I wouldn't even say that it does that. For all we know he's variable shadowing.

Comment: @toto: I strongly recommend that you delete this answer -- it's just that wrong.

Comment: @Hovercraft It can't be variable shadowing since `volatile` fixed it, no?  (I assume variable shadowing means you declare twice the same variable.)

Comment: @toto: I have no idea what's causing his problem based on the code so far posted.